# How to use PS calculated properties to collate data into a cell?

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject, calculated-property

I'm stumped on this one. I have a PS custom object with strings only and I want to build a report where I'm outputting strings of data into a new pipeline output object.

```
$myObjectTable | 
Select-Object @{
    n = "OldData";
    e = { 
        $_ | Select-Object name, *_old | Format-List | Out-String
    }
},
@{
    n = "NewData";
    e = {
        $_ | Select-Object name, *_new | Format-List | Out-String
    }
}
```

Running this produces blank output.

I tried running the code above with just the $_ object in the expressions, but I only got ... as the output. Wrapping the expressions in parenthesis did not change the output.

Comment: you will need `| Format-Table -Wrap` after that expression if you want to properly display that object in your console. Also adding `| ForEach-Object Trim` after each `Out-String` will help removing those empty lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...` as property value means that the value is either a multi-line string or it just didn't fit in a tabular format. See [**Using Format commands to change output view**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-7.3) more details.

You can fix those empty lines added by [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.3) using [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0). Then if you want to properly display this object having multi-line property values, [`Format-Table -Wrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.3#-wrap) will be needed.

Here is a little example:

```bash
[pscustomobject]@{
    Name = 'foo'
    Something_Old = 123
    Something_New = 456
} | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        OldData = $_ | Format-List name, *_old | Out-String | ForEach-Object Trim
        NewData = $_ | Format-List name, *_new | Out-String | ForEach-Object Trim
    }
} | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Resulting object would become:

```
OldData                                  NewData
-------                                  -------
Name          : foo                      Name          : foo
Something_Old : 123                      Something_New : 456
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. The console output from this was garbage because I have some very long strings, but outputting to a CSV made it look exactly as a I needed. Thank you.